# What is the simplest way to classify airplan manuvers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction, pattern-recognition

Suppose we have declared four motion types for air-plane. If we represent each maneuver with a trajectory line, what is the best classification method to retrieve the trajectory pattern with a similar trajectory shape to the new trajectory path? The proposed method should be able to classify partial paths so that we can predict maneuver type before it becomes complete.
Thank for your help.

Comment: I would try something like functional pca or use a smooth version of the trajectory shape and build some clasification model upon it. Here I would suggest to try different methods to see how they perform.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Druss2k. Could you possibly tell me if there is something like DTW Which is capable of handling paths with different lengths?

Comment: Ive never worked with DTW but my suggestions is based upon a presentation I recently saw. They id'd the movement and shape of animals by that method (though the pca was used to identify shape). The classification of the movement information was used because different animals have different movement patterns. They had small films of a sonar where they traced the movment of the centroid over time (3-dimensional space because no info on depth). I think you could approach your problem in a similar way. This will be not the most sophisticated solution but it will probably give a vaiable solution.